# What do the ahruf and Qira'at refer to in the Islamic literature?

Tags: quran, hadith, qiraat

While looking into the Islamic scriptures I came across two terms, Ahruf and Qira'at. Both seem to began with seven varieties. Later on, as time passed by more have been added to them. What do they both mean? How they differ from one another? As of now, how many of each of them are available among Muslims?

Comment: The Sahih Mutawatir are only 7 Ahruf, and the Qira'at are derived from these 7 Ahruf. So the Qira'at are all based on the 7 Ahruf of the Quran.

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi sorry but what is your basis of the misleading claim that "The sahih mutawatir are only 7 ahruf", it is mentioned in the sahih hadith yes. But that's all we can agree about. And whether the 7 ahruf are still existing is not agreed upon by all scholars.

Comment: There are questions asking about the meaning of the ahruf and the tag [tag:qiraat] should lead you to answers on this topic. So please check the site prior to asking duplicates and come back if you have a question or something missing that is not yet answered or addressed. Further as is written this question is too broad

Comment: @Medi1Saif Sorry so you're claiming that the Sahih Mutawatir is more than 7 Ahruf? I've never heard of that before. My basis: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQqHMtL4mFw

Comment: @OmarAlSuwaidi no I'm saying that the sahih hadith said that qur'an was revealed with 7 ahruf. That the qur'an we have now has more is your misinterpretation. There are some scholars who said it has only one harf.

Comment: @Medi1Saif So what about my original comment do you not agree with and see as 'totally misleading'? I never claimed that the Quran we have today has more?